# парсинг/анализ сайтов Scrapy или jsoup

Tags: jsoup, scrapy

Здравствуйте, есть ли возможность парсинга/анализа страницы на присутствие определенных слов. Слова желательно что бы были в отдельном внешнем файле. То есть такой аналог ctrl-f, но в автоматическом режиме. Смотрел Scrapy и jsoup, но именно такого процесса не обнаружил.
Что нужно:
файл который, например, в консоли выдаёт результат парсинга/анализа заданной страницы (внутри файла) и выдача результата (наличие слов из внешнего файла на заданной странице. 
Может быть есть более удобные способы ?

Comment: как задать [хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
Формулировка вашего вопроса создаёт больше вопросов, чем ответов. Возможно стоит добавить какой-то пример того, что хотите получить

Comment: есть внешний файл со списком слов. Пускай это будут названия производителей машин. Парсер при заходе не страницу (диапазон прописан например вот так:
name = 'Auto search'
 allowed_domains = ['www.auto.ru']
 start_urls = ['https://auto.ru/moskva/cars/all/']
ищет все совпадающие название и выводит их во внешний файл, например вот так: -o autosearch.csv
Основная задача это искать не по тегам или названиям классов , а просматривать страницы все целиком.